# SSRS - Trying to pass lengthy parameters to a report and opening in a new window

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008, rdl

I am trying to  open a report (From a report which is RDL) in a new window by using the command:

```
<Action>
    <Hyperlink>="javascript:void(window.open('http://...&param1=ddd&param2=fff&....
```

This is working fine for less number of parameters. But, For lengthier ones, The pop-up window is not getting opened. My client is using browser, IE 6, 7 & 8. This is not working in any of these 3 IE versions. Is there any way to make this request to be a POST method instead of GET. Can we write Javascript function inside RDL. Please guide to find a solution for this. I an new to SSRS.

Thanks,

Vivek

Answer (score 5):

You can POST data to reporting server URL with parameters as form variables.

Example -

```
<form id="frmRenderReport" action="http://YOUR_REPORT_SERVER_URL" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="rs:Command" value="Render" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rc:LinkTarget" value="main" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rs:Format" value="HTML4.0" /> <!-- report format -->
    <input type="hidden" name="rc:Parameters" value="false" />  <!-- display report parameters -->
    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="ddd" /> <!-- Parameter 1 -->
    <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="fff" /> <!-- Parameter 2, etc -->
    <input type="submit" value="Generate Report"/>
    </form>
```

Note: the name(s) of parameters have to match the names defined in the RDL