# SSRS - is it possible to call a SSRS report using hidden parameters, i.e. no parameters in the url?

Tags: php, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am trying to call up a ssrs report from my php page, but I dont want anyone to see the parameters in the url.  I would like to feed in the parameters using hidden fields within my php/html that calls the report. Has anyone tried this before?  If so, could you supply me with an example of how its done or even a link to a site that discusses this?  I have looked for some time and was unable to find anything on this topic.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Parameters can be passed using POST method. Check [SSRS - Trying to pass lengthy parameters to a report and opening in a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520915/ssrs-trying-to-pass-lengthy-parameters-to-a-report-and-opening-in-a-new-window). Note that this is still insecure since all traffic is in plain text and can be easily revealed.