# Changing PerformancePoint to use POST instead of GET

Tags: sharepoint, post, reporting-services, get

We have some SSRS reports that are deployed through sharepoint. We also have hooked up PerformancePoint dashboard to allow users to filter values. The PerformancePoint dashbaord passes the parameters to the reports. However, PerformancePoint passes these parameters as a GET, which has a ~2000 character limit in the URL. We have many parameters, so the URL exceeds the character limit and the page wont load.

Im wondering how I can change from GET to POST, and where I would make this change?

Im new to enterprise web development, so I apologize if my explanation was unclear. Sharepoint, Performancepoint, Dashboard, master pages, aspx, .., are new to me and quite confusing.

Comment: I think is not possible check this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e1a69cfe-2426-4dfd-82ad-516622fa09e2/passing-large-filter-values-from-performance-point-2010-filter-to-report-viewer-parameter?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

Comment: I was trying to do something similar and found this...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520915/ssrs-trying-to-pass-lengthy-parameters-to-a-report-and-opening-in-a-new-window